# Objectbox Flutter/Dart CMake 3.11 or higher is required error where CMake 3.16.3 is installed

Tags: flutter, objectbox

Error occurs when "start debugging" menu item on vs code is selected. Error details:

> Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode... CMake Error at
> flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/objectbox_flutter_libs/linux/CMakeLists.txt:1
> (cmake_minimum_required):   CMake 3.11 or higher is required.  You are
> running version 3.10.2 Exception: Unable to generate build files
> Exited (sigterm)

However CMake version is higher:

> $ cmake --version
>
> cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

Development environment details:

> Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Flutter Stable 2.5.2

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  objectbox: ^1.2.0
  objectbox_flutter_libs: any
   
dev_dependencies:
  objectbox_generator: any
```

I have tried Flutter beta channel, and going back a few Objectbox versions. Always the same error.

Comment: There was a similar issue related to using Flutter via a snap, see https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/317

Comment: Yes, that's making a lot of sense. Flutter Snap has it's own version, while the objectbox package is requiring a higher version. I'll install Flutter without using snap and provide an answer if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the snap install of Flutter and reinstalling Flutter manually resolved the issue.